# jQuery select all checkboxes within table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a table with multiple checkboxes in each row, and I created some jQuery to check all the chekboxes on a certain row by clicking another checkbox.

```
$('table').on('change', '.selectAll', function(e) {
      if(this.checked) {
          $(e.target).closest('tr').find(".aCheckbox").each(function() {
                $(this).attr('checked', true);
          });
      }
      else {
        $(e.target).closest('tr').find(".aCheckbox").each(function() {
                $(this).attr('checked', false);
          });
      }
});
```

But it will only work twice (i.e: you can check all the boxes, uncheck them, but then after that nothing will happen when I try to check them again)

When I'm clicking my .selectAll checkbox it is changing the input's html to `checked='checked'` successfully but no change is visible.

What is the problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the `checked` *property*, not the `checked` *attribute*. You also don't need to iterate, so I simplified the function for you:

```
$('table').on('change', '.selectAll', function (e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find(".aCheckbox").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```